# Mass update child records using apex class visualforce page with javascript

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I'm having a problem in using javasacript to display an error while mass updating a child record of an opporunity once I found the picklist ed_sp_ls__c='return' and the value ed_vpo_n__c=0 of at least one child record.
Here is my code behind:
// apex class

```
public String trouve {get;set;}
// constructeur de la classe
trouve ='IN Constructor';
public pageReference checkpo(){

        OppID = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        lstPO = [Select ed_sp_ls__c, ed_vpo_n__c From Poste_offre__c where Opportunite__c =: OppID];

        system.debug(logginglevel.error,'#######this.columnToSave '+this.columnToSave);
        if(this.columnToSave=='ed_sp_ls__c' ){
        system.debug(logginglevel.error,'#######Opportunite__c '+OppID);
        system.debug(logginglevel.error,'#######lstPO '+ lstPO);
        system.debug(logginglevel.error,'#######this.columnToSaveInIf '+this.columnToSave);
            for(Poste_offre__c po : lstPO){
                if(po.ed_sp_ls__c == 'retenu' &&  po.ed_vpo_n__c == 0)
                trouve ='true'; break;
                }
         system.debug(logginglevel.error,'#######trouve aprés init : '+trouve);
        }
        return refreshPage(false);
      }
```

// visualforce page:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="checkpo" action="{!checkpo}" status="spinningwheel" 
                             rerender="res,pageMessages"/>

<apex:outputPanel id="check" >
<script>
    var t  = '{!trouve}';
    checkpo();
   if(t=='true'){
    alert('Error, Status is 'return' and volume is 0');
    } 
</script>

</apex:outputPanel>
```

On debug log: trouve ='IN constructor' not 'true' wich doesnt let the message error to display

Any troubleshoot

Comment: When posting code, it's useful if you strip out anything irrelevant, such as debug statements and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Your javascript has a string with quotes that are not escaped. This is probably why no message is shown.

```
<script>
    var t  = '{!trouve}';
    checkpo();
   if(t=='true'){
    alert('Error, Status is \'return\' and volume is 0');
    } 
</script>
```

Besides that, `checkpo` is called asynchronously. The entire structure of what you're trying to do makes it highly improbable that it will work as you intend. You'll probably want to do something like this:

```
<apex:inputHidden value="{!trouvue}" id="result" />

<script>
function checkResult() {
    var x = document.getElementById("{!$Component.result}").value;
    if(x == "true") {
        alert("Status is \"return\" and volume is 0");
    }
 }
<apex:actionFunction name="checkpo" action="{!checkpo}" status="spinningwheel" 
                         rerender="result,res,pageMessages" oncomplete="checkResult()" />
```